# Is it possible to show a README file as markdown on Jupyter dashboard the same as on GitHub?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, readme

I tried to put a README file (.md) on Jupyter dashboard the same as I do on GitHub for showing it as a markdown cell (it shows the content without specifically opening the file).
Does anyone know if it's even possible? or it's only possible on GitHub?

Thanks!

Comment: so do u want to show markdown in jupyter?

Comment: Exactly, Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately by default NO. If possible you can write your own extension

Comment: Is this still not possible? :o